# My package compiles, the get functions work except for the doubles it prints a random number

Tags: c++

My package compiles, the get functions work except for the doubles it prints a random number. Any ideas?

```
#ifndef Package_H
#define Package_H


#include <string>

using namespace std;

//The class Package is the base class for derived classes TwoDayPackage and OverNightPackage

class Package //begins class Package 
{ 
public: 
    Package(const string &, const string &, const string &, const string &, const string &, const string &, const string &, const string &, const string &, const string &, double = 0.0, double  = 0.0); //constructor 

    //set and get functions for sender 
    void setSenderName(const string &); 
    string getSenderName() const; 

    void setSenderAddress(const string &); 
    string getSenderAddress() const; 

    void setSenderCity(const string &); 
    string getSenderCity() const; 

    void setSenderState(const string &); 
    string getSenderState() const; 

    void setSenderZip(const string &); 
    string getSenderZip() const; 

    //set and get functions for recipient 
    void setRecipientName(const string &);   
    string getRecipientName() const;   

    void setRecipientAddress(const string &);   
    string getRecipientAddress() const;   

    void setRecipientCity(const string &);   
    string getRecipientCity() const;   

    void setRecipientState(const string &);   
    string getRecipientState() const; 

    void setRecipientZip(const string &);   
    string getRecipientZip() const; 

    void setWeight(double); 
    double getWeight() const; 

    void setShip(double); 
    double getShip() const; 

    double calculateCost() const; 
    void print() const;

private: 
    string senderName; 
    string senderAddress; 
    string senderCity; 
    string senderState; 
    string senderZip; 
    string recipientName; 
    string recipientAddress; 
    string recipientCity; 
    string recipientState; 
    string recipientZip; 
    double weight; 
    double shipCost; 

};

#endif
```

.

```
//next page
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "Package.h"

Package::Package(const string & sname, const string & saddress, const string & scity, const string & sstate, const string & szip, const string & rname, const string & raddress, const string & rcity, const string & rstate, const string & rzip, double weight, double shipCost) 


{ 
    senderName = sname; 
    senderAddress = saddress; 
    senderCity = scity; 
    senderState = sstate; 
    senderZip = szip; 
    recipientName = rname; 
    recipientAddress = raddress; 
    recipientCity = rcity; 
    recipientState = rstate; 
    recipientZip = rzip; 
    setWeight(weight); 
    setShip(shipCost); 

} 



void Package::setSenderName(const string & sname) 
{ 
    senderName = sname; 
} 

string Package::getSenderName() const 
{ 
    return senderName; 
} 



void Package::setSenderAddress(const string & saddress) 
{ 
    senderAddress = saddress; 
} 

string Package::getSenderAddress() const 
{ 
    return senderAddress; 
} 



void Package::setSenderCity(const string & scity) 
{ 
    senderCity = scity; 
} 

string Package::getSenderCity() const 
{ 
    return senderCity; 
} 




void Package::setSenderState(const string & sstate) 
{ 
    senderState = sstate; 
} 

string Package::getSenderState() const 
{ 
    return senderState; 
} 




void Package::setSenderZip(const string & szip) 
{ 
    senderZip = szip; 
} 

string Package::getSenderZip() const 
{ 
    return senderZip; 
} 




void Package::setRecipientName(const string & rname) 
{ 
    recipientName = rname; 
} 

string Package::getRecipientName() const 
{ 
    return recipientName; 
} 



void Package::setRecipientAddress(const string & raddress) 
{ 
    recipientAddress = raddress; 
} 

string Package::getRecipientAddress() const 
{ 
    return recipientAddress; 
} 



void Package::setRecipientCity(const string & rcity) 
{ 
    recipientCity = rcity; 
} 

string Package::getRecipientCity() const 
{ 
    return recipientCity; 
} 



void Package::setRecipientState(const string & rstate) 
{ 
    recipientState = rstate; 
} 

string Package::getRecipientState() const 
{ 
    return recipientState; 
} 


void Package::setRecipientZip(const string & rzip) 
{ 
    recipientZip = rzip; 
} 

string Package::getRecipientZip() const 
{ 
    return recipientZip; 
} 




void Package::setWeight(double weight) 
{ 
    weight = (weight < 0.0 ) ? 0.0 : weight; 
} 
double Package::getWeight() const 
{ 
    return weight; 
} 



void Package::setShip(double shipCost) 
{ 
    shipCost = ( shipCost < 0.0) ? 0.0 : shipCost; 
} 

double Package::getShip() const 
{ 
    return shipCost; 
} 

double Package::calculateCost() const 
{   
    return weight * shipCost;
} 

void Package::print() const
{
cout<<"Sender:"<<endl
    <<senderName<<endl
    <<senderAddress<<endl
    <<senderCity<<", "<<senderState<<" "<<senderZip<<endl
    <<endl
    <<"Recepient:"<<endl
    <<recipientName<<endl
    <<recipientAddress<<endl
    <<recipientCity<<", "<<recipientState<<" "<<recipientZip<<endl
    <<endl
    <<"Weight of package: "<<weight<<" oz."<<endl
    <<"Type of delivery: Regular Delivery"<<endl
    <<"Cost of package: $"<<calculateCost()<<endl;
}

//The class TwoDayPackage is the first derived class from class Package




//The class OverNightPackage is the second derived class from class Package
```

.

```
//main function

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using std::setprecision;

#include "Package.h"
/*#include"overnighttest.h"
#include"twoday2.h"*/
//Test File

int main() 
{ 
   Package message("chris beyer","1 westwood circle","edison","nj","08820","mike b","1 westwood cirle","edison","nj","08820",10.00,1.50);

    /*OverNightPackage box("John Doe", "789 Fire Street", "Hell", "MI", "48169", "Jane Doe", "987 Leg Sun Crossing", "Intercourse", "PA", "17534", 10.00, 1.50, .85); 

    TwoDayPackage parcel("John Doe", "789 Fire Street", "Hell", "MI", "48169", "Jane Doe", "987 Leg Sun Crossing", "Intercourse", "PA", "17534", 15.00, 1.05, 5.00);*/



    cout << fixed << setprecision(2); 

    cout<<"Package delivery services program"<<endl
    <<endl
    <<"Cost per ounce for a package: $.50/ounce"<<endl
    <<"Additional cost for two day delivery:  $2.00/ounce"<<endl
    <<"Additional cost for overnight delivery: $5.00/ounce"<<endl<<endl;


    vector<Package*> myPackages;

Package *messagePtr=&message;
/*TwoDayPackage *TDpPtr=&TDp;
OvernightPackage *OpPtr=&Op;*/

myPackages.push_back(messagePtr);
/*myPackages.push_back(TDpPtr);
myPackages.push_back(OpPtr);*/

double total=0;

for(int i=0;i<myPackages.size();i++)
{
    cout<<"Package #"<<i+1<<":"<<endl<<endl;
    (*myPackages[i]).print();
    cout<<endl;
    total+=(*myPackages[i]).calculateCost();
}

cout<<"Total cost for all the packages: $"<<total<<endl;

system("pause");

    return 0;


}
```

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tag it as such so we can give you more appropriate answers.

Comment: Not many people will want to read through all this code to try to guess where your problem is, let alone even debug it for you. Show some effort: try to distill your problem down to a reproducible case that takes ten or fifteen lines to demonstrate your problem. (I'm almost positive 95% of this code isn't at all related to your problem.) And try to clearly state your problem in English. (I don't care if your English is _poor_; just try.)

Comment: This getter/setter mess is not how we do things in C++, or in any language really - the Java "gurus" are not skilled, and they are lying to you about what OOP is and how it works.

Comment: im only limited to 150 characters sorry about the lack of my english skill. Basically when i compile my hw the get functions return the values that i assigned to them, but the double values come back with a random number and it is -9255963134931783...etc, trust me if there was an easier way to do this i would be open, but this is my homework and i must do it this way

Comment: for example on my screen is reads, the senders informations, the recipients informations, but the weight of pakage prints -9255... etc

Comment: @cbeyer123:  Do not add more comments in this spacehere.  Instead, edit your original question to include more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your setters, you're not setting the instance variables. For instance: `weight = (weight < 0.0) ? 0.0 : weight` just changes the temporary variable used for the argument. You can either change the name of the parameter, change the name of the instance variable (recommended), or use the syntax `this->weight = ...`

Comment: Thank you jpm i figured it out, it was exactly what you said. Thanks again

Comment: Not to sound greedy, but since you're new here, I'll just remind you that upvotes and/or accepting answers that you find helpful is much appreciated. Glad you got it figured out.

Comment: According to stack overflows rules unless i have a 15 or higher on my reputation i can not give upvotes.